# Counting an XML attribute in Groovy

Tags: groovy

So I'm making a script in Groovy that parses a really large XML file, appends some stuff and slightly changes each element every time it appends. Each of these elements has an ID number associated with it and I want to make it so that every time an element is appended, the ID number will = the highest ID number in the file +1. I'll show a little piece of code to that will help understand:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xliff xmlns="xyxy" version="1.1">
  <file original="zzz.js" source-language="en" target-language="en" datatype="javascript">
    <body>
    <trans-unit id="20" resname="foo">
        <source>foofoo</source>
        <target>foofoo</target>
      </trans-unit>
      <trans-unit id="21" resname="blah">
        <source>blahblah</source>
        <target>blahblah</target>
      </trans-unit>
     </body>
  </file>
</xliff>
```

In this case, if I added an element (trans-unit) to the list, the ID would need to be 22. I have an algorithm that parses and appends, but I'm not sure how to increment the ID each time. Again, I'm using Groovy to do this. Does anyone have an idea? Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have parsed that XML with xmlslurper or xmlparser, you should be able to get the next id with the help of `max`:

```
def xml = '''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xliff xmlns="xyxy" version="1.1">
  <file original="zzz.js" source-language="en" target-language="en" datatype="javascript">
    <body>
    <trans-unit id="20" resname="foo">
        <source>foofoo</source>
        <target>foofoo</target>
      </trans-unit>
      <trans-unit id="21" resname="blah">
        <source>blahblah</source>
        <target>blahblah</target>
      </trans-unit>
     </body>
  </file>
</xliff>'''

def x = new XmlSlurper().parseText(xml)
def next = 1 + x.file.body.'trans-unit'*.@id*.text().collect { it as Integer }.max()

assert next == 22
```

To use `XmlParser`, you need to change the line to:

```
def next = 1 + x.file.body.'trans-unit'*.@id.collect { it as Integer }.max()
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but it doesn't seem to work the same way with XmlParser()? Maybe I'm doing something wrong.

Comment: @awallace04 added the change required for `XmlParser`